# Recursion function in XML using Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, xml, recursion

*i am trying to make html page, that should shows all the nodes in xml   file. there are other ways but i want to do it using javascript DOM through  recursive function.   i've tried this. suggest please.*

**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Adi the great</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var httpreq=null;
       var response=null;
       setTimeout("loadDoc()",100);
       setTimeout("loadDocument()",1000);
       function loadDoc()
        {
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
                httpreq=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            else
                httpreq=new ActiveXObect("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            httpreq.open("get","ADI_SUPPORT.xml",true);
            httpreq.send(null);
            //httpreq.onreadystatechange=loadDocument;
        }
       function loadDocument()
        {
            res=httpreq.responseXML;
            play("loaded");
            traverse(res.documentElement);
        }
       function traverse(element)
        {
            play("inside function with element =>"+element.nodeName);
            len = element.childNodes.length;
            play(element.nodeName + " is node with len = "+len);
            if(len>1)
            {
                play("len is > 1");
                temp="";
                for(i=1;i<len;i+=2)
                    temp+=element.childNodes[i].nodeName+",";
                play("temp="+temp);
                for(i=1;i<len;i+=2)
                {   
                        play("started element "+element.childNodes[i].nodeName+" at i="+i);
                        traverse(element.childNodes[i]);
                        play("ended element "+element.childNodes[i].nodeName+" at i="+i);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                play("node ends with "+element.textContent);
            }
        }
       function play(x) { document.write(x + "<br/>"); }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**